# pytest parametrize is not able to identify the argument parsed

Tags: python, pytest

I need to parse the returned list to the parametrize marker which is not working

```
@pytest.yield_fixture()
def elements():
    """
    This function helps us to fetch a list
    """
    return [1,2,3]

@pytest.mark.parametrize("ele", ids=elements)
def test_check(ele):
    print(ele)
```

It just throws out the error ...

```
collecting conftest.py      _________________________________________________________________
../venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pluggy/hooks.py:289: in __call__
     return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)

../venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py:68: in _hookexec
     return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)

../venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py:62: in <lambda>
     firstresult=hook.spec.opts.get("firstresult") if hook.spec else False,

../venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/_pytest/python.py:239: in     pytest_pycollect_makeitem

res = list(collector._genfunctions(name, obj))

../venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/_pytest/python.py:415: in _genfunctions
self.ihook.pytest_generate_tests(metafunc=metafunc)

../venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pluggy/hooks.py:289: in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)

../venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py:68: in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)

../venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py:62: in <lambda>
    firstresult=hook.spec.opts.get("firstresult") if hook.spec else False,

../venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/_pytest/python.py:142: in     pytest_generate_tests

metafunc.parametrize(*marker.args, **marker.kwargs)

E   TypeError: parametrize() missing 1 required positional argument:     'argvalues'
```

How can I parse the list to the parametrize object ?

Comment: What is the purpose of this generator? Why not just `it = iter([1,2,3])`, and then do stuff with `it`?

Comment: how is it different from what I have shown above ?

Comment: When you call `next` on the iterator, it returns the next element provided by the iterator - as in this case next is only case next is only called once, only the first element of the iterator is yielded

Comment: Whenever you call `elements`, `iter` is called again, and so you get a new iterator every time you call it, which start back at the first entry. If I'm understanding what you want, it looks like you don't need the `elements` function at all. Instead, just create one iterator object and re-use it. As an example, `a = [1,2,3]; it = iter(a); print(next(it)); print(next(it)); print(next(iter(a))` prints 1, 2, 1.

Comment: Don't you just want to `yield iter([1,2,3])` inside the fixture?

Comment: A `yield` in a fixture is not a generator `yield`, it's for running code in fixture on test teardown. Yield fixture will not act as a generator in test; you are probably looking for [parametrizing fictures and test functions](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html)

Comment: @Dennis, I have made the attempt already. But this is not my requirement. When I call the test_check(env); it hits the fixture. The fixture must have recursive logical bindings that it will give the first element, then again the test_check() must call itself automatically and gets the second element from the list by hitting the fixture and the same process until the entire length of the list is covered.

Comment: @hoefling, no that was not my requirement. :)

Comment: @RobertHamilton, yes that's correct. But how can I yield the further elements ?

Comment: @BharathKashyap right now it looks like your requirement, based on the desired output.

Comment: You'd either have to pass the iterator and handle it in the test function, or check out pytest's parameterized tests to run the function with each value